# OpenSCAD Batch Export individual Files via Shellscript

Tags: macos, shell, openscad

I copied a code in OpenSCAD to generate keychain files, and I have a variable "name" that I change to adjust the file. Now, I want to use a list of names from a "names.txt" file to export multiple files with the adjusted names.

Here is the shellscript I am currently using:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the names.txt file exists
if [ ! -f names.txt ]; then
    echo "Error: names.txt file does not exist!"
    exit 1
fi

# Get the names from the names.txt file
names=$(cat names.txt)

# Generate the STL files
for name in $names; do
    # Generate the STL file
    /Applications/OpenSCAD.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenSCAD -o "$name".stl -D name="$name" generator.scad

    # Check for errors
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error generating STL file for $name"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

The script seems to run correctly, but I get a warning:

`WARNING: Ignoring unknown variable 'EVA' in file keychain_nametag_generator.scad, line 85`

(The variable "EVA" is the first name in my list)

The OpenSCAD file starts with this line:

`name = read_string();`

The files are generated, but without the names. I have spent most of the night trying to fix it, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you overlooked this in the [OpenSCAD User Manual](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Using_OpenSCAD_in_a_command_line_environment#Constants):

> Be aware that your shell (bash, cmd, etc.) parses the arguments before passing them to `openscad`, therefore you need to properly quote or escape arguments with special characters like spaces or quotation marks. …

So you could write:

```
…/OpenSCAD -o "$name".stl -D name=\""$name"\" generator.scad
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!
It just worked with the scape arguments, awesome.